# HSL to RGB conversion

Tags: coloring

I have some problems understanding the formulas for conversion from HSL to RGB color model.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Let's take for example H = 60 degrees, S = 0.7. L = 0.5.

And we start with C, which is 1 - | 1 - 1 | x 0.7 = 0.7 (if `x` means to multiply them, does it mean to multiply?)

Then H' is 1.

```
And now how to find X? 

X is C( 1 - 1 ) isn't it? But what means C( of something) :S
```

Then we find m = 0.5 - 0.35 = 0.15.

Can someone continue my example and tell if the steps so far are correct and especially how to find X. Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: These formulas appear on the following wikipedia-page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB. Just a note.

Comment: Yes, I know, I took the pictures from there, but the problem is that I can't understand them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your steps so far are correct, and the $\times$ means multiplication.

By $X = C(1-|H'\text{ mod }2 - 1|)$, they mean $X = C\times(1-|H'\text{ mod }2 - 1|)$. A common convention in mathematics is to leave out multiplication signs when no confusion can arise (and apparently, also when it can).

This leads to
$$ X = 0.7\times(1-|1-1|) = 0.7 $$
and thus to $(R_1,G_1,B_1) = (0.7,0.7,0)$. Then $(R,G,B) = (0.85,0.85,0.15)$.

Comment: Oh thank you really much. I feel quite stupid now. :D I imagined C( some stuff ) as a function of something and was really wondering what is this, when C isn't a function :D (too much C++, I think...) Thank you once again for your answer :) and please excuse me for my absent-mindedness and stupidity :S

Comment: You're welcome. And there's no need to apologize, we're all here to learn (even if it's only conventions).

Comment: I know this convention, of course, it's learned maybe in second or third grade, it just slipped at the moment. Thank you once again. :)